# Problem working in models rendering admin add page

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I tried so many things like `.formate` and using id explicit in the model now I don't know what to do.

```
class Horas_medica(models.Model):
   id_boxes = models.ForeignKey(Boxe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   id_medico = models.ForeignKey(Medico, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   id_paciente = models.ForeignKey(Paciente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   descripcion = models.TextField()
   diagnostico = models.TextField()
   created_date = models.DateTimeField(
           default=timezone.now)
     
   def __str__(self):
      return str(self.id)
```

Error in console is:

```
error TypeError: str returned non-string (type tuple)
```

Comment: Try this: `return f'{self.id}'`

Comment: @AjayLingayat  the result is the same https://prnt.sc/vov2pw  :(  for some reason is the only one that doent work https://prnt.sc/vov4ja

Comment: I don't think the error is here at this model can you share the complete `models.py` code?

Comment: @AjayLingayat https://github.com/SebastianCSilva/consulta-medica/blob/master/panel_principal/models.py  thanks for the  help  bro <3

Comment: From your models.py you're returning a tuple on some models where you intend to return a string. Example `Paciente` returns `return self.rut, self.nombre, self.apellidos` which is a tuple. Change to `return "%s %s %s" % (self.rut, self.nombre, self.apellidos)`.

Comment: You can also do this for `Medico` . Change to `return "%s %s %s" % (self.rut, self.nombre, self.apellidos)`

Comment: You can also try this : `return f'{self.rut}@_{self.nombre}@_{self.apellidos}'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Paciente(models.Model):
    nombre = models.TextField()
    apellidos = models.TextField()
    rut = models.TextField()
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()
    direccion = models.TextField()
    genero = models.ForeignKey(Genero, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rut, self.nombre, self.apellidos


class Medico(models.Model):
    nombre = models.TextField()
    apellidos = models.TextField()
    rut = models.TextField()
    contrasena = models.TextField()
    direccion = models.TextField()
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()
    genero = models.ForeignKey(Genero, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rut, self.nombre, self.apellidos
```

From your `models.py` you're returning a tuple on some models where you intend to return a `string`.

For instance `Paciente` returns `self.rut, self.nombre, self.apellidos` which is a tuple. Change to `return "%s %s %s" % (self.rut, self.nombre, self.apellidos)`

You can also do this for `Medico` . Change to `return "%s %s %s" % (self.rut, self.nombre, self.apellidos)`